# Adding variables and text to a string?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make a string grab a set text and a variable? Something like this:

```
std::string morning = "morning";
std::string str = "Good " [insert morning here] ", user!";
```

Obviously I'm trying to do something a bit more complex than the example I just gave, but I believe you can kinda understand what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: do you want to concatenate strings? Or string with numbers too?

Comment: Which C++ book are you using? String concatenation is fairly basic.

Answer (score 2):

You simply use `std::string::operator+`, something like:

```
std::string str = "Good " + morning + ", user!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::string morning = "morning";
unsigned int user_id = 384;
std::ostringstream out_stream;
out_stream << "Good " << morning << ", user #" << user_id;
std::string str = out_stream.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither ostream nor the operator+ worked. I ended using some char and push_back stuff. Anyway, thanks guys!